# FIrefox is not rendering correctly webpages and messes with their styling

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint, firefox-quantum

I have the default theme on **Firefox 66.0.2** for Linux Mint. I have noticed that most pages don't show up as they should or as, for example, they show in Chromium.

Is this something widespread, and how can I fix it?

This site:
[image: this site]

Quora:
[image: quora]

DuckDuckGo:
[image: duckduckgo]

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, *technically* Firefox is doing nothing wrong. It's rendering textboxes and textareas like they would be rendered natively in the OS (it delegates to the OS look-and-feel when the element has not been excessively styled with CSS). If the website owner wanted to ensure those fields had black text on a white background, they could write that in their stylesheets.

The second screenshot is obviously more of a concern. Given my experience from many years back, I am guessing that this is a combination of two things:

- The website doesn't specify a background colour as the developer has assumed it will always be rendered white by default (naughty, naughty!)
- Firefox has been configured to use a default page background color of dark gray.

You can try to fix this by searching for 'colors' in your Options page. Open up the Colors window and adjust as necessary.

[image: Options: Colors]

For the third screenshot, all I see that's broken is the search button, which is showing an s for 'Search' instead of a magnifying glass icon. It could be down to failing to load the required icon-font that turns 'S' into the magnifying glass, or the font isn't compatible with Mint for some reason.